# remove '.part1' from Output directory in 7z

Tags: python, cmd, 7zip, unrar

I have 2 files `test.part1.rar` and `test.part2.rar`
When extracting them using command

```
7z x -o* test.part1.rar
```

The output directory is a folder with `test.part1` name
I want the output directory to be a folder with name `test` (archive name without '.part1')

```
    From 7z documantation
    
        -o{dir_path}
        {dir_path}
        This is the destination 
directory path. It's not required to end with a backslash. If you specify * in {dir_path}, 7-Zip substitutes that * character to archive name.
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be less stressful to fix it after?  `mv test.part2/* test.part1` / `mv test.part1 test`?

Comment: Yes but i am writing a code to decompress multiple files not just one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) will do what you seek.

```
f=test.part1.rar; 7z x -o ${f%%.*} $f
```

You may want to use the [7z e](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/extract1.htm) command if you don't want to extract with the full paths within the archive.

The `*` can be used within the output directory to be replaced by the archive name. It doesn't sound like you need that.

Comment: The problem is that * is not replaced by archive name when extracting multipart rar files ,but it is replaced by archive name+part1

Comment: I see what you mean. You could do something like `f=test.part1.rar; 7z x -o ${f%%.*} $f`